# Django API Rest Framework

Tags: django

this is - don't slap me in the face - a beginner question.

I have some knowledge in Python and Django, but it is not too overwhelming. I have a very appealing business idea in my head and I made it a challange to see if I can get the nessesary skills to make it come to life.

Long story short, somewhere along the road I want to be able to build an IOS and Android App (or bring someone in who can do it). I also need a homepage for this (Django is a good enough solution for this - this much I know).

As far as I unserstand it, I can use the rest API Framework to connect Apps with the Django Backend. Is this a good solution? Or would you recommend another way to realise this projekt?

Speed would be impartant for the final solution. Also I need good scalability, though, I don't plan to recreate Facbook.

Comment: I build mobile apps for a living using Phonegap, and I've used Django REST Framework for the back end very successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was motivating! Great!

Comment: One quick question if you have the time for it. How is scalability with your solution? Does it depend totally on Django? What is the potential (speed, scale) in comparison to a native Java solution?

Comment: The speed of Django itself or Python is not really an issue. The biggest bottleneck tends to be the database, but that would be the case with any other backend too, and it can mostly be resolved by refactoring the queries to be more efficient and implementing caching. If the backend is still too slow it may be worth setting up something like Varnish in front of the API. Any time-consuming tasks like sending emails can be delegated to Celery tasks. Otherwise, I wouldn't worry too much as it's a problem to deal with once you get big enough for it to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Django REST Framework is brilliant, and the documentation is really helpful (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), takes a little while to get used to but with django experience its very simple. There is also a short video tutorial(4 videos) by a guy called thenewboston https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yw7gETuRKjw which will help get you started.

Hope this helps, good luck with the business adventure

Comment: Thanks for the help! That was all the answer I needed and wanted!